# How can I update top 100 rows in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I know that in standard SQL you can do this:

```
update top (100) table1 set field1 = 1
```

(reference: [how can I Update top 100 records in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198364/how-can-i-update-top-100-records-in-sql-server))

But this is not allowed in DB2.  Can anyone advise me on how to accomplish the same result in DB2?  Thanks!

Comment: `TOP x` is not in the SQL standard, it's an extension unique to MS SQL Server (and probably Sybase).  [`FETCH FIRST x ROWS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause) was introduced in SQL:2008

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is dooable, although you may not get the results you expect...

First, *always remember* that SQL is inherently **UNORDERED**.  This means that there is *no such thing* as the 'top' rows, unless you explicitly define what you mean.  Otherwise, your results are 'random' (sortof).

Regardless, this *is* dooable, presuming you have some sort of unique key on the table:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = 1
WHERE table1Key IN (SELECT table1Key
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE field1 <> 1
                    ORDER BY field1
                    FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY)
```

*Why* do you only want to update 100 rows at a time?  What sort of problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no unique identifier on the rows, which adds to the fun, but I have found a similar solution based on the example you provided, so thank you.  100 is not a hard limit, but rather a way to keep from grabbing the entire table if there are tens of thousands of records. Essentially, I have a scheduled process on a JEE server that runs across a number of instances that checks for records in this table, grabs them 100 at a time and processes them into another location.  I want to mark the first 100 with a batch ID, select them, loop through and process, then delete by batch ID

Comment: I found that it can be done a little less verbosely: `UPDATE (SELECT table1Key FROM table1 WHERE field1 <> 1 ORDER BY field1 FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY) SET field1 = 1`

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the `RRN` (if you're just concerned with limiting the number of updates)?

for example:

```
update mytable a set a.field = 'foo' where RRN(a) < 200
```

Comment: Not for a process like this. RRN() is okay for a non-volatile file, but this file is having rows inserted and deleted. By default, SQL tables will have REUSEDLT(*YES), so rows may be inserted in the previously deleted rows' slots. It'd be too easy to update the wrong rows with a batch number, or maybe worse delete a row that was inserted at RRN()=1.