# T-SQL How to update the bottom/last row only?

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, record

I want to update the bottom/the last row in my table. I have try to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198364/how-can-i-update-top-100-records-in-sql-server) solution, but nothing seems as correct syntax:

```
UPDATE TOP(1) @ResultTable
SET PeriodLastDate=DATEADD(DAY,-1,PeriodLastDate)
ORDER BY PeriodID DESC
```

OR

```
UPDATE TOP(1) @ResultTable
SET PeriodLastDate=DATEADD(DAY,-1,PeriodLastDate)
FROM @ResultTable
ORDER BY PeriodID DESC
```

What I have till now working is:

```
UPDATE @ResultTable
SET PeriodLastDate=DATEADD(DAY,-1,PeriodLastDate)
WHERE PeriodID=(SELECT COUNT(PeriodID) FROM @ResultTable)-1
```

but this will not always works, as in my function some of the records are deleted and I am not always having PeriodIDs incremented with 1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM @ResultTable
ORDER BY PeriodID DESC
) 
UPDATE CTE SET PeriodLastDate=DATEADD(DAY,-1,PeriodLastDate)
```

Answer (score 9):

There's not enough context in your question to give a bulletproof answer. Based on your working solution, how about instead of looking for the count look for the max PeriodID? As long as subsequent PeriodID's are a greater value it should work to get the "last" record.

```
UPDATE @ResultTable
SET PeriodLastDate=DATEADD(DAY,-1,PeriodLastDate)
WHERE PeriodID=(SELECT MAX(PeriodID) FROM @ResultTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique column (perhaps PeriodID?) in each row you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE @ResultTable
SET PeriodLastDate=DATEADD(DAY,-1,PeriodLastDate)
where <unique column> = (select top 1 <unique column> 
  from @ResultTable
  order by PeriodID desc
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
UPDATE ResultTable SET PeriodLastDate='NewValue' WHERE ID= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ResultTable)
```