# Update Table and Set for top rows from select statement

Tags: sql-server

Got a single SQL table which I am wanting to query and update top 5 rows when doing so. The following does not work (hence the question) but might explain what it is I am trying:

```
UPDATE 
    TempStaging
SET 
    pending = 'running'
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 scan FROM TempStaging
         WHERE pending = 'outstanding')
```

Comment: UPDATE has TOP clause,
also exists duplicate article 
[how can I Update top 100 records in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198364/how-can-i-update-top-100-records-in-sql-server)

Comment: Assuming that you have some sort of key on which you are ordering the records:

Comment: Your query is wrong.  After `FROM` you should use a table name but you used a SELECT-statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to `UPDATE`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT TOP 5 pending  
   FROM TempStaging
   WHERE pending = 'outstanding'
)
UPDATE 
    ToUpdate
SET 
    pending = 'running'
```

**Note:** `TOP` used without an `ORDER BY` clause will select 5 *arbitrarily specified* records.

**Edit:** To get the `Name` values of the records being updated you can use the [**`OUTPUT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, as already noted in the comment by @C. White:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT TOP 5 pending, name  
   FROM #TempStaging
   WHERE pending = 'outstanding'
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET pending = 'running'
OUTPUT inserted.name
```

Comment: Thanks - If have 2 columns name & pending how do I output name for these same top 5 rows?

Comment: @dross What do you mean by *output name*? This is an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: For this example:

    ;WITH ToUpdate AS (
       SELECT TOP 5 pending  
       FROM TempStaging
       WHERE pending = 'outstanding'
    )
    UPDATE 
        ToUpdate
    SET 
        pending = 'running'
    OUTPUT
        inserted.pending
        ,inserted.name

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos: I would like the name value for the affected rows to be returned by the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to use the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause to select the values... embedding an `IN (SELECT TOP 5 ...)` should do it.

Example:

```
create table ##dummy (pk int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, vals varchar(50));
INSERT INTO ##dummy (vals) VALUES 
  ('updateme')
  ,('updateme')
  ,('updateme')
  ,('updateme')
  ,('updateme')
  ,('leavemealone')
  ,('leavemealone')
  ,('leavemealone')
  ,('leavemealone')
  ,('leavemealone')
  ,('leavemealone')
  ,('leavemealone')
  ,('leavemealone')

SELECT * FROM ##dummy
UPDATE ##dummy
  SET vals = 'fixed!'
WHERE 
  pk in (SELECT TOP 5 pk FROM ##dummy ORDER BY pk)
SELECT * FROM ##dummy

DROP TABLE ##dummy
```

So with your particular example, it is probably:

```
UPDATE 
  TempStaging
SET 
  pending = 'running'
WHERE
  scan IN (SELECT TOP 5 scan FROM TempStaging WHERE pending = 'outstanding' ORDER BY scan)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: With original question I asked in mind I have marked Giorgos Betsos answer as correct for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE Top(5) TempStaging SET pending = 'running' WHERE pending = 'outstanding'
```