# Reading Data in thread return same record

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, task

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in multiple task but it might be giving data from cache.

Here is my code:

```
var entities = new PhonePushEntities();
var lst = Task.Run(() => entities.GetInAppAlertBatch("ios", DataPacketSize).ToList());
```

This code is also running in parent task.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInAppAlertBatch]
    @DeviceType as varchar(10),
    @PSize as int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    begin tran InApp_Fetch_Process
    declare @t as TABLE (id int)

    insert into @t
    SELECT top (@PSize) sKey FROM InAppAlerts 
    where JobStatus = 'pending' AND DeviceType = @DeviceType

    UPDATE InAppAlerts
    SET JobStatus = 'inprocess'
    where sKey in (SELECT id from @t)

    select * from InAppAlerts where sKey in (select id from @t)

    COMMIT TRAN InApp_Fetch_Process
END
```

My question is logically: if we see the stored procedure, then each time it should return unique data, but it is returning the same record for some threads.

Comment: And what's the question? Or what's wrong? What do you need to help with?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy, Logically if we see the SP then each time it should give unique data, but is is giving me same record for some thread.

Comment: Are you saying that running *N* number of threads/tasks concurrently results in each getting the same results?  It *would* make sense given your structure.  Your transactions would block on the update, but essentially update the same list of records.

Comment: @EbenRoux yes you are right, Running N number of thered. How I solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a different temporary table @t for each thread?

Comment: @jdweng yes I do have

Comment: Are you clearing the table(s) when you start running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that multiple concurrent threads or tasks are returning the same results you could solve it by not first selecting the records.  Select statements do not block each other.

What I would recommend is that you update the required records in the transaction with a unique identifier and then select those.  Since you will be uniquely marking some records you should be ok.  You'll need a new column for this though.  Try something like this (untested):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInAppAlertBatch]
    @DeviceType as varchar(10),
    @PSize as int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    begin transaction

    declare @guid uniqueidentifier = newid()

    update top (@PSize) InAppAlerts set padlock = @guid
    where JobStatus = 'pending' and  DeviceType = @DeviceType

    select * from InAppAlerts where padlock = @guid

    commit
END
```

If you need ordering on that take a look at Martin Smiths answer: [how can I Update top 100 records in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198364/how-can-i-update-top-100-records-in-sql-server)

Comment: This is become dead lock when 2 thread trying to read record same time

Comment: That is somewhat odd.  Is there anything else accessing the same data that perhaps interferes?