# How to UPDATE TOP(n) with ORDER BY giving a predictable result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, queue, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to read the top 100 items of a database table that is being used like a queue. As I do this I'm trying to mark the items as done like this:

```
UPDATE TOP(@qty)
    QueueTable WITH (READPAST)  
SET 
    IsDone = 1
OUTPUT
    inserted.Id,
    inserted.Etc
FROM
    QueueTable 
WHERE
    IsDone = 0
ORDER BY
    CreatedDate ASC;
```

The only problem is, according to [UPDATE (Transact-SQL) on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx), the `ORDER BY` is not valid in an `UPDATE` and:

> The rows referenced in the TOP expression used with INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE are not arranged in any order.

How can I achieve what I need which is to update the items at the top of the queue while also selecting them?

Comment: Can you use TOP with ORDER BY to get a list of Unique ID's which will be the top 100 (sorted / ordered) rows and only update the table where they contain these IDs? Here's an example with a CTE: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9241466/6167855

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I Update top 100 records in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198364/how-can-i-update-top-100-records-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server allows you to update a derived table, CTE or view:

```
UPDATE x
SET 
    IsDone = 1
OUTPUT
    inserted.Id,
    inserted.Etc
FROM (
select TOP (N) *
FROM
    QueueTable 
WHERE
    IsDone = 0
ORDER BY
    CreatedDate ASC;
) x
```

No need to compute a set of IDs first. This is faster and usually has more desirable locking behavior.

Comment: It's possible. The OP already seems to do that. Any expression at all works.

Comment: You can do select top (@var) ... note that the brackets are required.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of SQL Server this was made possible in.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Good to know it, I miss the brackets before.

Comment: @usr Do you think it would be necessary to put a WITH (UPDLOCK) on the select to make this thread safe?

Comment: No, SQL applies the same locking behavior as usual. All of this appears undocumented... but many people use it and I have verified it myself. Updatable views (and equivalently derived tables and CTEs) are a black art to me.

Comment: @MartinBrown, `top (@Var)` appeared in 2005. Btw, you can even correlate a subquery this way.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in SSMS, it works fine. You may need to do some modification accordingly.

```
--create table structure
create table #temp1 (
    id int identity(1,1),
    value int
)
go

--insert sample data
insert #temp1 values (1)
go 20


--below is solution
declare @qty int = 10
declare @cmd nvarchar(2000) =
N'update #temp1
set value= 100
output inserted.value
where id in
(
    select top '+ cast(@qty as nvarchar(5)) +' id from #temp1
    order by id
)';

execute sp_executesql @cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ranking function (for example row_number).

```
update top (100) q
set IsDone = 1
output
    inserted.Id,
    inserted.Etc
from (
    select *, row_number() over(order by CreatedDate asc, (select 0)) rn
    from QueueTable) q
where rn <= 100
```